# Mqtt connection failed with exception 'Not authorized to connect (5)' android

Tags: java, android, mqtt, watson-iot

Hi I am trying to connect to mqtt with my android device that I just registered but it I keep getting the error

```
Not authorized to connect (5)
```

This is some of my code

```
        client = new MqttAndroidClient(context, connectionURI, clientID);
        client.setCallback(callbacks);

        String username = IOT_DEVICE_USERNAME;
        char[] password = this.getAuthorizationToken().toCharArray();

        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setCleanSession(true);
        options.setUserName(username);
        options.setPassword(password);

        Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to server: " + connectionURI);
        try {
            // connect
            return client.connect(options, context, listener);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught while attempting to connect to server", e.getCause());
            throw e;
        }
```

where **IOT_DEVICE_USERNAME** is a string **"use-token-auth"**
and **connectionUri** is **"tcp://<"organization">.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:8883"**

Something else that is interesting is that right before this error I get this log

```
Unregister alarmreceiver to MqttServiced:<"organisation">:<"DeviceType">:<"deviceId">
```

Here is the stackTrace of the error

```
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err: Not authorized to connect (5)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:28)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.notifyReceivedAck(ClientState.java:988)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:140)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-06 12:27:24.214 9009-9009/wibicom.wibeacon3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Hi Michael, if you me know the 6 character organization, I will check the logs for any errors that may help troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Also, are you following any recipe or tutorial?  For example, this recipe shows how to set the client ID with the device type and ID.  i.e, String iotClientId = "d:"+ORG+":"+DEVICE_TYPE+":"+DEVICE_ID;  https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/android-wear-iot-bluemix/

Comment: @ValerieLampkin 4rxa4d is the organization. There should be some other devices types connecting smoothly but the android devices are the ones having trouble

Comment: @ValerieLampkin I was currently referring to <https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-starter-for-android> I will look at the recipe above. Let me know if you find anything. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. I was indeed using this as the client id in as an imput to the constructor of the MqttAndroidClient object.

```
String iotClientId = "d:"+ORG+":"+DEVICE_TYPE+":"+DEVICE_ID;
```

However, since I regestered the Android device as a gateway because it is actually connecting to multiple peripherals where the sensors actually are. To fix this, I the above line to

```
String iotClientId = "g:"+ORG+":"+DEVICE_TYPE+":"+DEVICE_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this error:

*Token auth failed (Device/gateway not found in database): ClientID='d:4rxa4d:AndroidDevice:1c39476b8dd0'*

Have you created a device type for AndroidDevice and registered the ID 1c39476b8dd0 to your org in the Watson IoT Platform?

This [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-register-devices-in-ibm-iot-foundation/) shows how to register devices.

Comment: Interesting, I do have the device registered on Watson IoT already. Is it not finding the device? What would you recommend? Maybe delete the device and register it again?

Comment: I updated the question adding the stacktrace of the error if that is any help to understand what happened.

Comment: Hi Michael, I see you discovered it was registered as gateway and not device and now have updated the connection info accordingly.  Glad to hear it is working now.